Why is one of the roots of this quadratic so well approximated by power mean?
I have a quadratic of the form:
$$y=x^{2}(1+n)-xn(a+b)-ab(1-n)$$
and I realized that the root that I'm interested in is equal to or well approximated by the power mean of $a$ and $b$
$$x=\left(\frac{a^{n}+b^{n}}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Here is a desmos graph showing this numerically: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aqbu4inebp
How can I prove analytically that the power mean is equal to or approximates the root?
I suspect this is an instance of a broader theorem and I'm just too much a rookie mathematician to know it. I'd be very interested if someone could provide more context on this.
Many thanks for your help!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Define “well approximated”.

Unfortunately, I'm too much of an amateur to give a precise meaning, at least at the moment.  Analytically, I can show they are exactly equal when n=0, n=-1, and n=1 (which is what made me realise how the general mean might approximate all the other cases). Otherwise, all I can say is that, numerically, the two are "very close" for all values of a,b, and n that I try, as shown in the graph.
I've been working on this for a while now, still feel none the wiser. Any tips would be amazing.
